# Is there a tool to draw GeoJSON points on a raster image?

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson

I know there are tools like geojson.io which allow me to draw points on a real world map. But I work on a fictional map, so all I have is a big raster image. Later I want to show it in Leaflet using CRS.Simple.

So what I want is a tool that let's me put points on a raster image and gives me a GeoJSON with pixel coordinates instead of latlon.

My google-fu failed me, so I thought I'd ask here if anyone knows of a tool that can do this. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem with using real-world tools to implement fantasy constructs is that you have to manifest enough details in your construct that the real-world tools will function. GeoJSON in particular is based on longitude/latitude values, so you'd have to create a [fantasy projection](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/story-maps/mapping/mapping-a-better-route-from-the-shire-to-mount-doom/), too.

Comment: hmm... I just assumed that the geojson file itself would not care if I just put in xy values instead of longitude and latitude. And as my leaflet app is using CRS.Simple aka working with pixel coords, I thought it might take those simple coords from the geojson. But appearently it's not that easy...